# How send arguments in hexadecimal linux terminal

Tags: python, c, linux, arguments

I have a C programm compiled with gcc in linux 32 bits without stack protectors. This program have one argument and this is a string with hexadecimal values (for send to stack for buffer overflow).

My run example is:

```
./myprogram.out `python -c "print 'A'*91+'\x20\xee\xff\xbf"`
```

My problem is with \x20 value. This is interpreted as ASCII 32 (whitespace) and it is interpeted as end of parameter and the value save in the stack is 00 (null value, end string).

Example of values in stack (hexadecimal):

....**41 41 41 41 00 EE FF BF** .....

For me, \x20 is a part of a memory address to save in the stack for this reason i need to save 20 in hexadecimal in the stack.

Comment: It could be have been worse. You could have been trying to pass null bytes in the command-line parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the result of `` so that it isn't split by the shell.

BTW assuming an sh variant, `$()` is usually preferable to ``.  Both at the same time results in

```
./myprogram.out "$(python -c "print 'A'*91+'\x20\xee\xff\xbf'")"
```